# JavaScript numeric self equality

Tags: javascript, numbers, lodash, nan

I recently came across the following code:

```
function baseClamp(number, lower, upper) {
  if (number === number) {
    if (upper !== undefined) {
      number = number <= upper ? number : upper;
    }
    if (lower !== undefined) {
      number = number >= lower ? number : lower;
    }
  }
  return number;
}
```

The conditional at the beginning of the function is interesting.

```
  if (number === number) {
```

I tested the following in Chrome:

```
var number = undefined;
number === number
true
number = null
number === number
true
number = NaN
number === number
false
```

Does `number === number` simply check for NaN or is there more to it?

Comment: It checks for `NaN`, indeed. It's one of the easiest checks for that, as `isNaN` is a bit...broken.

Comment: [Comparing NaN with NaN ordinarily—i.e., using either double equals or triple equals—evaluates to false, because IEEE 754 says so.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: I disagree with this being a duplicate (of the post provided.) While the answer(s) may be duplicated, the question is worded quite differently. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/. It'd be unlikely that I'd click on the other question if using a search engine and seeing its particular title.

Answer (score 3):

`number === number` simply checks if `number` is not `NaN`. `NaN` is the only value which is not equal to itself.

`number === number` can be replaced with `!Number.isNaN(number)` in modern browsers (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)).

Comment: on the replacement: I agree. I believe lodash does the self equals check for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` is the only value in ECMAscript that does not equal itself.

This function is equivalent to `Math.min(Math.max(number, lower), upper)` and seem to behave the same. It will skip any processing if `number` is `NaN`.

```js
function baseClamp(number, lower, upper) {
  if (number === number) {
    if (upper !== undefined) {
      number = number <= upper ? number : upper;
    }
    if (lower !== undefined) {
      number = number >= lower ? number : lower;
    }
  }
  return number;
}

function mathClamp(number, lower, upper) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(number, lower), upper);
}

console.log([-10, 0, 10, NaN].map(it => [baseClamp(it, 0, 10), mathClamp(it, 0, 10)]));
```